Solana parsing created token from a contract
Why do I don't get all the new token created from the contract here :
from solana.rpc.async_api import AsyncClient
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
import time

# Adresse du contrat
CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P"
# URL HTTP RPC pour obtenir les détails des transactions
RPC_URL = "https://rpc.shyft.to?api_key=VMTouOFcUzCMhHjQ"

async def monitor_new_tokens():
    client = AsyncClient(RPC_URL)
    last_checked = int(time.time())  # En secondes

    print(f"Monitoring new tokens created by contract {CONTRACT_ADDRESS}")

    while True:
        response = await client.get_signatures_for_address(
            Pubkey.from_string(CONTRACT_ADDRESS),
            before=None,
            limit=10
        )
        
        if not response.value:
            print("No transactions found.")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            continue

        for tx in response.value:
            # Vérifie uniquement les transactions après le dernier contrôle
            if tx.block_time and tx.block_time > last_checked:
                print(f"New transaction detected: {tx.signature}")

                # Obtenir les détails de la transaction
                tx_details = await client.get_transaction(tx.signature)

                if tx_details.value:
                    instructions = tx_details.value['transaction']['message']['instructions']
                    
                    for instruction in instructions:
                        if 'programId' in instruction and instruction['programId'] == "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA":
                            parsed = instruction.get('parsed', {})
                            if parsed and parsed.get('type') == "initializeMint":
                                mint_address = parsed['info']['mint']
                                print(f"New token detected: Mint Address = {mint_address}")
        
        last_checked = int(time.time())  # Met à jour l'heure du dernier contrôle
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

# Exécute la fonction principale d'écoute des nouveaux tokens
asyncio.run(monitor_new_tokens())


This is a shot in the dark, but can you request the transaction with json-parsed encoding instead? Ie:
                tx_details = await client.get_transaction(tx.signature, encoding="jsonParsed")

